# In Python, is it possible to trigger an event when a class is instantiated?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need an event to be triggered whenever an object is created for a particular class. Is that possible in python?

Comment: either `__init__` or `__new__` might do the trick for you

Comment: although not it's not an event but a magic method / constructor

Comment: @Nenri The idea is that the event can be triggered (whatever that means to the OP) *from* `__init__` or `__new__`.

Comment: this is a little bit of a vague question, you need to provide more details on the exact use case